# Multiply in SQL just if result is not NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, nullif

I have the following query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN houses.level = 'top' THEN users.id END)::float / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)) 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN houses ON houses.user_id = users.id
```

And instead of a ratio, I want to return a percentage, so I changed it to:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN houses.level = 'top' THEN users.id END)::float / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)) * 100
FROM users
LEFT JOIN houses ON houses.user_id = users.id
```

However, if the denominator (`NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)`) returns null, it means I will be multiplying `NULL` * 100. How can I just return NULL without multiplying if the denominator is 0 (and therefore null because of the NULLIF).

Comment: Why are you concerned if `NULL` is multiplied by 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to multiply an INT with NULL. The result will still be NULL.

Try it yourself:

```
SELECT NULL * 100
```

Comment: Also works as expected in MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want NULL to represent 0%, use COALESCE:

```
SELECT COALESCE((COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN houses.level = 'top' THEN users.id END)::float / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)) * 100, 0) ...
```

COALESCE returns the first non-null thing it encounters, working from left to right

Otherwise, go for what Nobita recommends ; let null be null